# Copy files and images from samsung s3 even when its almost turned off

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

First of all my samsung s3 is stuck on the samsung logo splash screen so i'm thinking of doing a factory restore , that's not an issue for me but i want to copy images and videos at least from the inner memory not the sd card to my laptop or pc is there any way to do that ? i seriously do not wanna lose those pictures .

Answer (score 0):

A factory reset will not wipe the sdcard partition. In most cases, you can restore some application data like that (ex: WhatsApp). This might differ for an S3 but I know this is the behavior on Nexus devices.

Another option if you have a custom bootloader is that you *might* be able to access the internal memory using `adb shell`.